# Python Tornado request JSON

Tags: python, json, ajax, tornado

My application accepts data from POST method which I am running through JQuery's AJAX request. I am sending JSON formatted data, but in handler as I accept request and access the data it turns out to be byte string type.

I am using  `my_body = self.request.body` method.

For example, if I am sending `{"drzava":"rs","kategorija":"general"}` received data looks like `b'drzava=rs&kategorija=general'`.

Problem is, afterwards I can't use `tornado.escape.json_decode()`, to make it dictionary. I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stefan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1697, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 164, in post
    telo_json = tornado.escape.json_decode(telo)
  File "/home/stefan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/escape.py", line 83, in json_decode
    return json.loads(to_basestring(value))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I will post the code, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** Firstly, there was a typo in my `.js` file, so `AJAX` requests weren't being sent. Secondly, Tornado was detecting default `POST` method (not the `AJAX`'s one), so you have to manually override it by saying something like `e.preventDefault();` where `e` is parameter of anonymous function in `JQUERY`'s action. On the other side, in Tornado, result of `self.request.body` is something like `b'{"country":"rs","category":"sports"}'` which **can** be transformed to dictionary using `tornado.escape.json_decode()`. Many thanks to @Ionut Ticus for constructive suggestions.

So, after bit of investigating and reading docs, I found the following:

> HTTPServerRequest.body is now always a byte string (previously the
>   default empty body would be aunicode string on python 3)

This is written it Tornado's official documentation.
[Tornado Documentation Release 6.0.4 page 183](https://www.tornadoweb.org/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/)

Hovewer, I found a way around it.

```
argumenti = self.request.arguments
drzava_val = argumenti['drzava'][0].decode("utf-8")
kategorija_val =  argumenti['kategorija'][0].decode("utf-8")

data = {
            'drzava': drzava_val,
            'kategorija': kategorija_val
        }
```

Comment: The code above will raise an exception if any parameter is not specified which is not ideal; use `self.get_body_argument(KEY, DEFAULT_VALUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

The data you receive in your Tornado server application depends on how your data is being "packaged" by the client.

You could have `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (seems to be your case above) which you can process in Tornado using `get_body_argument`:

```
drzava = self.get_body_argument("drzava", None)
kategorija = self.get_body_argument("kategorija", None)
```

or you could have `application/json` (seems to be want you want):

```
data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```

In order to send JSON data from your browser you need to **actually send JSON data** and specify the content type:

```
var data = {"drzava":"rs", "kategorija":"general"};
$.ajax({
    url: YOUR_URL,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    ...
```

EDIT:
In the end the issue was that the HTML page was sending the data using a form and would not actually use the JS code.

Comment: This is exactly how I have been sending data.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `data: JSON.stringify(data)`? Because from your question above it seems you are not.

Comment: Yes. Here is .js script running on page: `var posiljka = {
      drzava: $drzava.val(),
      kategorija: $kategorija.val()
    };

    $ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'localhost:8000',
      data: JSON.stringify(posiljka),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(){
        alert('poslato');
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('greska');
      }
    });`

Comment: You're using `dataType: "json"` which is used to tell the server what **response** you expect; `contentType` is used to specify what you **send**.

Comment: Yup. Corrected it, still same result.

Comment: Make sure you are testing the correct JS code and not some cached version because there's no way you can get `b'drzava=rs&kategorija=general'` by using `JSON.stringify`. Use a debugger or print statements to check the values while testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210604/discussion-between-ionut-ticus-and-laika-boss).